# Convert a projected raster into a csv maintaining its original grid form

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I have to convert some projected rasters (with ndvi values) into csv or excel files. I want to keep the grid form, with the first row as metric lon values and the fist column as metric lat values. At the intersection there should be the ndvi value.

I usually use 'as.data.frame(raster, xy=T)' to export values as data frame but in this precise case I would obtain a sort of values matrix.

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
ncell(r)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
plot(r)

df <- as.data.frame(r, xy=T)
head(df)

    x  y layer
1 -162 81     1
2 -126 81     2
3  -90 81     3
4  -54 81     4
5  -18 81     5
6   18 81     6
```

What I want

```
  1   2   
1 v1  v2
2 v3  v4
```

An then, write.csv...

Comment: Not clear about the output.  How do you want the head(df) to be

Comment: The output should be a data frame

Comment: I meant what those values v1, v2, v3, v4

Comment: ok, they're the ndvi values present in the original raster

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution passing from 'as.data.frame' to 'dcast'

```
df <- as.data.frame(raster, xy=T)
d1 <- dcast(df, y~x, value.var = "layer")
d2 <- d1 %>% arrange(-y)
```

Not elegant, but works. Any other methods?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `as.matrix` for this.

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)

m <- as.matrix(r)
write.csv(m, "test.csv", row.names=F)

read.csv("test.csv")
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
#1   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
#2  11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19  20
#3  21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29  30
#4  31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39  40
#5  41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49  50
#6  51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59  60
#7  61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69  70
#8  71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79  80
#9  81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89  90
#10 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```

You could also create the matrix like this

```
mm <- matrix(values(r), ncol=ncol(r), byrow=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If we need a tidyverse approach

```
library(tidyerse)
df %>%
   spread(x, layer) %>% 
   arrange(desc(y))
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
xtabs(layer ~ y + x, transform(df, y = factor(y, 
                 levels = sort(unique(y), decreasing = TRUE))))
```